# - (minus) values for constraint to margins, etc.?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a basic but necessary question regarding constraining a view to the margins of its container. For example to constrain a label to the main view container you can set these constraints directly within interface builder and I have seen a tutor select -20 value for left (leading) and the same for the right side. 
The aim was to pin this label directly to the left and right edges of the view enclosing it.
Just wondering why this wasn't just 0 value rather than -20?

What purpose do the minus values have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Just wondering why this wasn't just 0 value rather than -20

Because the tutor blew it. This constraint was made to the *margins* of the container, and those margins are *inset* from the edges by 20. Therefore, to reach the edges, the constant of the constraint value needs to compensate with an *outset* (the `-20`).

The correct thing to do was to make the constraint to the *edges* of the container. Then the constant, as you rightly suggest, would have been `0`.